# Facing issue while using GoogleAuthProvider() method

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

How to use `GoogleAuthProvider()` method in angular app for authentication in login method?

```js
     Angular version: ^12.2.7 
    "@angular/fire": "^7.0.4", 
    "firebase": "^9.1.0",
```

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/compat/auth';
// import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/compat/firestore';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { AppUser } from '../models/appuser';
import * as firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
import { GoogleAuthProvider } from "firebase/auth";
```

I'm getting error at:

```
firebase.GoogleAuthProvider(). async login() { const returnUrl = this.route.snapshot.queryParamMap.get('returnUrl') || this.router.url; 
localStorage.setItem('returnUrl', returnUrl); 
const credential = await this.afAuth.signInWithPopup(new firebase.GoogleAuthProvider()); 
return this.updateUserData(credential.user); }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can try importing GoogleAuthProvider like this:

```
import { GoogleAuthProvider } from "firebase/auth"

// ...signInWithPopUp(new GoogleAuthProvider())
```

If you want to use that `firebase.auth` namespace then you might have to downgrade Firebase to `"8.X.X"` or use compat version for imports:

```
// Add compat if using V9

import firebase from "firebase/compat/app"; 
import "firebase/compat/auth"
```

Comment: can you please correct me what is wrong in this method. I'm getting error at firebase.GoogleAuthProvider().
async login() {
    const returnUrl = this.route.snapshot.queryParamMap.get('returnUrl') || this.router.url;
    localStorage.setItem('returnUrl', returnUrl);
    const credential = await this.afAuth.signInWithPopup(new firebase.GoogleAuthProvider());
    return this.updateUserData(credential.user);
  }

Comment: My imports are correct for V9.

Comment: @YogeshNikam please share your imports as well.

Comment: import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/compat/auth';
// import { AngularFireAuth }  from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/compat/firestore';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { AppUser } from '../models/appuser';
import * as firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
import { GoogleAuthProvider } from "firebase/auth";

Comment: @YogeshNikam  you don't need `firebase.auth.` if you are importing from modular SDK as in my answer